# Kubernetes node different region in single cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have running kubernetes cluster in europe region and there are 4 nodes running in same region within cluster GCP, Now my requirement is i want 2 node in Asia region and other 2 node keep in europe, Is it possible to run node in multi region within cluster ? Or Can we setup node pool region wise to the cluster?

I am not talking about multi region cluster and cluster federation.

Comment: **Is it possible to run node in multi region within cluster** and **I am not talking about multi region cluster** - For me it seems contradictory. Can you pls elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GKE - then no, it is not possible to use nodes from different regions in single cluster. But it is possible to use several clusters and one Istio control plane. Read more here: https://istio.io/docs/concepts/multicluster-deployments

If you are using vanilla Kubernetes on GCP Compute instances - then yes, it is possible to create multi-region cluster in single VPC.

Comment: .. I don't want to use multi region cluster or federation. I just want to know that is it possible to add multi region node to single cluster. I have only one cluster and want to setup node in different 2 region within cluster.

Comment: As I said - in GKE it is not possible.